# Citations are not appearing from .bib file

Tags: bibtex

I'm using a .bib file for all my references, but after compiling the citations are not appearing correctly, the order is not correct and some are not appearing at all! I'm attaching a short part of the text as an example:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathrsfs,epsfig,color, url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy,hhmmss]{datetime}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}



\section{Four-fermion operator basis (Ref.\cite{Aguilar-Saavedra:2010uur})}
\label{sec:2}

\textbf{Q: How $O_{\ell q}^{1}$ and $O_{\ell q}^{3}$ is different ?}
\vspace{1 cm}

We follow the notation in Refs.~\cite{Buchmuller:1985jz,Arzt:1994gp} for gauge-invariant operators, introducing flavour indices $i,j,k,l = 1,2,3$. 

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr} 
\bibliography{refsEFT}



\end{document}
```

and the reference file 'refsEFT' contains

```
@article{Buchmuller:1985jz,
    author = "Buchmuller, W. and Wyler, D.",
    title = "{Effective Lagrangian Analysis of New Interactions and Flavor Conservation}",
    reportNumber = "CERN-TH-4254/85",
    doi = "10.1016/0550-3213(86)90262-2",
    journal = "Nucl. Phys. B",
    volume = "268",
    pages = "621--653",
    year = "1986"
}


@article{Aguilar-Saavedra:2010uur,
    author = "Aguilar-Saavedra, J. A.",
    title = "{Effective four-fermion operators in top physics: A Roadmap}",
    eprint = "1008.3562",
    archivePrefix = "arXiv",
    primaryClass = "hep-ph",
    doi = "10.1016/j.nuclphysb.2011.06.003",
    journal = "Nucl. Phys. B",
    volume = "843",
    pages = "638--672",
    year = "2011",
    note = "[Erratum: Nucl.Phys.B 851, 443--444 (2011)]"
}

@article{Arzt:1994gp,
    author = "Arzt, C. and Einhorn, M. B. and Wudka, J.",
    title = "{Patterns of deviation from the standard model}",
    eprint = "hep-ph/9405214",
    archivePrefix = "arXiv",
    reportNumber = "UM-TH-94-15, UCRHEP-125, CALT-68-1932",
    doi = "10.1016/0550-3213(94)00336-D",
    journal = "Nucl. Phys. B",
    volume = "433",
    pages = "41--66",
    year = "1995"
}
```

I'm compiling in the following sequence `pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex -> pdflatex`. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: unrelated but don't use `[utf8x]{inputenc}` or `epsfig` or `epstopdf` packages

Comment: what order do you get and which entry does not appear?

Comment: I only got first Ref appeared as Ref. 3 and nothing else!

Comment: What about these packages, are they obsolete now ?

Comment: Also during the BibTeX compilation it is showing that the '\filename.aux' can't be opened!

Comment: epsfig has been obsolete since 1994....

Comment: bobtex needs to read the aux file or there will be no bibliography. if your file is abc.trx run pdflatex abc then nibtex abc

Comment: As I said, my main file is a 'abc.tex' file and I'm running it in ```pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex -> pdflatex''' order, but still it is not working!

Comment: that would not give an error `'\filename.aux' can't be opened! `  it would give an error about `abc.aux`, which was why I asked.